# how can an android app using pre-populated sqlite database add new column or tables when used the 1st time by the user?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, android-studio

My app is quite simple, it's a flashcard app showing questions  and answers. so I pre-poulated it with a small sqlite database in the asset folder that will be copied to the app once installed.
I'm using using **SQLiteAssetHelper**.

Once installed by the user, the app add automatically in the first usage  some columns  or tables that will be populated with user data, like marked as favorite, seen before, edited...

My question is How can I add a new column or new table to the database automatically with the first use. Remember I'm using SQLiteAssetHelper.

Comment: Why don't you put those tables/columns into the asset DB?

Comment: to make the app lighter in term of size.